# Not able to install bower using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

I have Node.js installed on my system (v0.10.26) and I am trying to install the bower package manager. But I am not able to install. I keep getting an error. I placed my npm-debug.txt with jsfiddle for your reference.

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
D:\mySite>npm install bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/insight
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-root
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cardinal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-registry-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chmodr
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream-ignore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/junk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress-zip
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opn
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/promptly
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/p-throttler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request-progress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/retry
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lockfile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stringify-object
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shell-quote
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-config
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/archy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-endpoint-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-json
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-logger
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cardinal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-config
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/promptly
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chmodr
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/archy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lockfile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-root
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-json
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opn
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shell-quote
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request-progress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/p-throttler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stringify-object
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-endpoint-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/junk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/retry
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-logger
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-registry-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress-zip
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/insight
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream-ignore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cardinal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-config
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lockfile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/promptly
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chmodr
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shell-quote
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opn
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/p-throttler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-logger
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-json
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-endpoint-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request-progress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stringify-object
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/junk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/retry
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\update-noti
\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd D:\mySite
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! file C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\update-notif
package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-root
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/archy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress-zip
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-registry-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/insight
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream-ignore
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\mySite\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please find the jsfiddle link for log [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6BfQW/).

I also cleaned my npm cache and tried again, but this time I got this error:

```
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd D:\bower
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\bower\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you copy the content of  C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\update-notifier\0.1.8\package\package.json ? Also, you can try deleting C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache and start again, see if that fixes things.

Comment: I typed the above path, I am getting error as 'Windows can't find' C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\update-notifier\0.1.8\package\packag‌​e.json check the spelling and try again - what this mean?

Comment: Try `npm cache clean` and then `npm install bower`.

Comment: sure, let me try and get back to you.

Comment: I tried cleaning cache, still I am getting error. let me edit my question and post the error over there. I am in proxy setting.

Comment: Have a look over there then http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy

Comment: It is properly set. But I don't know why this is not working. I can able to install the stylus but I am not able to install bower-why?

Comment: If you have a package.json file, add a minimum json with name like this.  {
  "name": "xyz",
} and try again

Comment: This package has been deprecated
Author message:

We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/

Answer (score 0):

The is you have to specify the path to which bower should be installed. The path should be added either in your zshrc file or your bashrc file like this.

```
export PATH =/usr/local/lib/node_modules/:$PATH
```